# Database Deleting Rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

so this is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < users_table.RowCount; ++i)
{
    SQLDatabase.DatabaseRow row = users_table.GetRow(i); //get current ID.
    if (userID == users_table.GetRow(i)["ID"]) //if userID is the same as it's in the row
    {
        row["ID"] = "0";
        row["Name"] = "DELETED";
        row["Username"] = "DELETED";
        row["Password"] = "DELETED";
        row["UserType"] = "DELETED";
        row["LastLoginDate"] = "0";
        row["LastLoginTime"] = "0";
        users_table.Update(row);
    }
}
```

My goal is to delete a row. Sadly I'm unable to insert NULL values etc., any idea how I could delete that row? I would like to add that I do not have .delete functions or anything in particular. I would be glad if you could tell me how to add them.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this command set but have you tried `users_table.Delete(row)` without changing any values in `row`

Comment: What class is the `users_table`? you might just want to run a sql query on the database? `DELETE FROM Users WHERE ID = {yourId}`

Comment: Can someone explain to me what class does `DatabaseRow` come from ? I never seen it before :(

Comment: What type is SQLDatabase. Is this a own implementation or a library? never seen it before.

Comment: @H.Mikhaeljan , lol man , i thought i was the only one who didn't get `SQLDatabase` !!

Comment: @H.Mikhaelijan thats' my own implementation of library. :D Although, thanks for interest, problem has been fixed :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(This answer assumes you're using SQL Server)

You can easily execute SQL Commands using System.Data.SqlClient.
The connection string would be the connection details to your database instance. You can see some more examples of how to construct your connection string @ [Connection String Examples](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/). Also, when you're deleting rows from your database you want to utilize the DELETE command not the UPDATE. More details can be found on [DELETE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/delete-transact-sql)

```
    public void deleteRow()
    {
       string connectionString = "Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password = myPassword; ";
       string queryString = "DELETE FROM Test_Table WHERE ID = 5";
       using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
       connectionString))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for your kind help! You've seriously helped me, and now everything works as it should! Thanks again, have a great day or night ! :D